# Request had invalid authentication credentials - Google Calendar API

Tags: oauth-2.0, postman, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

I'm trying to to a request to the Google Calendar API using Postman. Following this Google documentation:
https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/?apix=true

I'm doing a:

```
GET  https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{my_calendar_id_here}
```

On the Postman Authorization tab i'm specifying that i want to use OAuth 2.0 and i also put my access token (which i use to make Calendar API calls from code, works fine). However, Postman responds with the following body:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Invalid Credentials",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "authError",
        "location": "Authorization",
        "locationType": "header"
      }
    ],
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}
```

I really don't understand what i'm doing wrong, and other answers don't seem to target my particular scenario. I'd be grateful if someone could point out what am i doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend replicating the request in [Google's OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/). Then using the confirmed to be working access token to troubleshoot Postman.

For Postman you could also pass the access token as a request header and if that resolves the issue.

**Postman Headers Tab Input:**

```
| Key           | Value                 |
|---------------|-----------------------|
| Authorization | Bearer {access_token} |
```